# Could not work unserialize() function in php and could not show data

Tags: php, serialization

following Code is not working in to unserialize data from MySQL.

```
$tempss = $row->session;
$contractors = unserialize($tempss);
foreach ($contractors as $contractor){
    echo htmlspecialchars($contractor);
}
```

Where

```
$tempss = 'a:3:{s:10:\"2017-07-01\";s:11:\"06:00-06:30\";s:10:\"2017-07-29\";s:17:\"06:00-06:30-07:00\";s:10:\"2017-07-27\";s:23:\"06:00-06:30-07:00-07:30\";}'
```

Comment: There shouldn't be backslashes in serialized data. Obviously you __serialize__ it wrong.

Comment: How was the array serialized in the first place? And I'm guessing that it comes from a database? How was it inserted?

Comment: oh.. actually i use WordPress; so it was automatically append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the **backslash**  this issue is coming just use **stripslashes**

like this

```
$contractors = unserialize(stripslashes($tempss));
```

It gives output as

[image]

I thing It will work for you.